# Realtime database using firebase - retrieving a specific information

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to create a real-time multiplayer quiz. I am using the Google Real-time Multiplayer API together with the firebase real-time database.

At the beginning of the game, users are prompted to ask themselves a question and provide two answers, where 1 answer is correct. Then this information is sent do Firebase Real-time Database under the child "Games" -- "mRoomId" --- "userId"

The variable uniqueRoomID is the specific id of the room which they players are retrieving from the Google API.

```java
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Games").child(mRoomId).child(userId);
```

And I send 4 values with the setValue function to that specific reference.

```java
Upload upload = new Upload(question,answer1,answer2, userId);

 myRef.setValue(upload);
```

**My database tree is as follows**

[image: My Realtime Database Structure]

**My question is:**

When I present a question to the other user later in the game, I don't want to show **my own** question, only the other user's question is relevant.

This is my valueEventListener:

```
 myReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Games").child(mRoomId);
  myReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      showData(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  });
```

And this is the method showData();

```
private void showData (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

  Upload upload = ds.getValue(Upload.class);
  Log.d("TAG", "question1 is  " + upload.getQuestion1() );

}
```

}

The log in showData is returning two different questions from the database because it loops through the children.

How do I get only one of the questions that is relevant to be presented to the user playing the game ?

Should I structure this differently, or is there a way to get only the values that are relevant to me?

Comment: Please add the code that you using now.

Comment: Which quiz question are you talking about (I can't see any node in your database named like that), how do you present a user the question. Please clear things out, the question is too ambiguous at the moment.

Comment: I have updated my question with relevant code

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to exclude a specific child node from a query. This means that (as far as I can see) you have two basic options:

1. Read both child nodes, and remove your own node client side based on the fact that its `DataSnapshot.getKey()` has the same value as `User.getUid()`.
2. Read only the child node of the other player. This requires that you somehow already know the key/UID of the other player, but would allow you to then load only that player's data with `DatabaseReference theirRef = database.getReference("Games").child(mRoomId).child(otherPlayerUid);`

Also see:

- [is it possible query data that are not equal to the specified condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582223/is-it-possible-query-data-that-are-not-equal-to-the-specified-condition)
- [Firebase retrieving all children except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375627/firebase-retrieving-all-children-except-one)
- [Firebase : How to read every child node in parent except children with particular data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416519/firebase-how-to-read-every-child-node-in-parent-except-children-with-particula)

Comment: 1: In my case the getKey is actually returning the child "mRoomId" which is identical for user1 and user2.

2: I have tried to find a way to easily share this information between the two users (userId), but I have no luck at the moment. It will get more complex later in the development because it might include 3- or 4 users aswell..